# Open Powershell script with pure c code

Tags: c, powershell, wincc

I want to make automatically screenshots of our visualiziation.
I managed to switch through the pictures.

But getting the screenshots is quite difficult.
I found an quite easy Powershell script that works fine.

But I have to call it with c Code due our visualiziation.
It offers only "Winexec" and "ProgramExecute".

I didn't manage to find the right code...

```
WinExec("Powershell -/Skript -Param1 -Param2", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

or
    `unsigned int ProgramExecute(char* Program_Name)`

Has anybody an idea where I can find the right order?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `powershell.exe /?` ?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-3.0).

Answer (score 0):

I use the fine software "greenshot" with automatic save.

No coding and almost anybody can create screenshots of the visualization ;)

..and sometimes powershell is not installed, or the security setting of the policy prohibits this kind of scripts from running correct...

//PerD